# Why it is not good design to align tabs at bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs

I know that we can place tabs on our convenient with top alignment or bottom alignments.But when i was reading the developer.android.com.The training section for lateral navigation has emphasized on the fact that tabs should not be used at bottom of the screen.But i don't find any reason why they are insisting someone to not use tabs at bottom.
Can any one explain me?

[you can find this article here](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html)

you can find that lines below figure 5 at the end of the paragraph.

advance thanks for giving attention to question.

Comment: Because people are used to them at the top.  That makes it awkward to have them at the bottom.  But if you want them at the bottom go ahead, its your app.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Consitency**: It is at the top in most apps
2. **Usability**: If you use eye trackers you see that users read a page from top to bottom. If the tabs are at the top they are easier to find.
3. **Option menu**: There is already an [option menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) at the bottom.

Comment: :what you are telling is perfect from user point of view.But it is not necessary that all user asks for same requirement.I am totally agree with you but i am asking for a good reason that makes me creating tabs at top.what will be the case if i use it at bottom,Is there any threat by coding point of view.Do all other functionality works same with both cases.Top and bottom.

Comment: If you make a web app it is tricky to have a footer navigation because old browsers do not support `position=fixed`. With Java I don't think there will be any difference. But as a programmer it becomes your problem if users give you bad rating/comments.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple, it's all about UserInterface Concepts (there are many out there, android has an own: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html ). One of them is "**Consistency**" - we users expect tabs (especially in android, but also in browsers) at the top and that's why they should stay there.

Also there are a few "famous" rules for userinterfaces. 
One set for example is from Shneidermann: http://faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/360/f04/sessions/schneidermanGoldenRules.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I'd think it's simply a matter of convention. Users would probably expect tabs to be towards the top of the page. It's comparable to putting a file menu to the far right of a menu bar rather than the left.